# GIT fatal: ambiguous argument 'mixed': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, github

```
$git reset --soft HEAD 1
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD 1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I was trying to use the soft reset method to reverse a previously done commit. I was expecting it to take two files I earlier committed back to the staged area so I can add a third file before committing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **revert your previous commit and get the files back to staging area**, run the below command

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Or

```
git reset --soft HEAD^1
```